# I am trying to use Sikuli in my Selenium Webdriver test but due to image resolution the test is not clicking the image

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, sikuli, sikuli-script

When performing my test I captured the image of the File Name input field from File Upload windows pop up. The image resolution on my local machine is a bit different from the image resolution on the Windows Server 2012 VM machine so test keeps on failing as it tries to match the File Name input field image that I have in the Selenium WebDriver project and the image that is displayed in the VM. How to handle the resolution issue. 

**Local Machine image**
[image: Local Machine image]

**Windows Server 2012 VM Machine image**
[image: Windows Server 2012 VM Machine image]

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do about it. Your only solution is to create your patterns based on the resolution of the target machine or alternatively change the resolution of the target machine to match the one you are using for pattern creation.

The other thing I find peculiar is how did you configure SikuliX to run on a VM? There is a known limitation that it cannot run in headless mode. Unless you have configured some kind of VNC. Just make sure that the error you're getting is caused by the reason you mentioned and not due to this limitation.

Comment: I didn't do any configuration in my VM for SikuliX I added SikuliXAPI.jar to my project and add maven dependency to POM.xml with systempath it worked for me.

Comment: @SujaiKrishna So you are running Sikuli remotely on a headless VM and it works for you? I am sorry but I find that hard to believe :)